# Print a triangle of numbers from a given input

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to get an output of the following a right triangle with a hollow middle and a right triangle with numbers :

```
*
**
* *
*  *
*   *
*    *
*     *
********
```

and

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
```

Here is my code so far

```
import kotlin.io.*
    
fun main() {
    print("Enter an integer: ")
    val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
    
    var i = 1
    
    while (i <= n) {
        for (j in 1..i) {
            print("*")
            println()
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

My output keeps coming out wrong.

Comment: Please edit your title to something concise and descriptive of the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Comments should explain why you are doing something. Not what you are doing. We can see that `var i = 1` is creating a var and setting it to 1. The comment “create a variable i and set it to 1” adds nothing here other than noise that a reader has to filter out. The code is fairly straight forward without the comments. But was very difficult to work out what it was doing when the comments were there as you have to filter past them.

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
val n = 8

for (i in 1..n) {
  for (j in 1..i) {
    print(if (j == 1 || j == i || i == n) "*" else " ")
  }
  println()
}

for (i in 1..n) {
  for (j in 1..i) {
    print(j)
  }
  println()
}
```

Execute it on [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/VYAjjwgxG)